# Taxonomy menu with custom path for taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, routes

I am trying to make a taxonomy menu using the [Taxonomy Menu module](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) with a custom path for the taxonomy terms. Instead of /taxonomy/term/tid I want /proj/!tid (or ultimately /proj/!term-name but I'll settle for what I can get). I have the taxonomy menu working fine when I leave the "menu path type" setting to default, which leaves it as /taxonomy/term/tid. Whenever I try to use the "vocabulary path" option though, the menu terms all disappear. I've tried to follow the instructions in the [documentation here](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy_menu).

I have a view with Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth) and Taxonomy: Term ID depth modifier arguments and a page display with the path set to proj/%. I've tried additionally making a url alias at proj and proj/% but that didn't seem to make any difference. But basically whenever I set the menu path type to "vocabulary path" ("custom path" in the documentation), the menu items all disappear. The terms are still there, and I can navigate to /proj/%, but there are no menu items.

Any help with how to have a custom path for the vocabulary while keeping the menu items would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to alter taxonomy term paths for taxonomy terms implemented by your module, then you can implement [hook_term_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_term_path/6), which is the hook that allows a module to alter the taxonomy term paths.

The function that returns the taxonomy term paths is the following:

```
    function taxonomy_term_path($term) {
      $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_load($term->vid);
      if ($vocabulary->module != 'taxonomy' && $path = module_invoke($vocabulary->module, 'term_path', $term)) {
        return $path;
      }
     return 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->did;
  }
```

Implementing that hook would also help to modify the path of any vocabularies, if the field `$vocabulary->module` is changed to the short name of the module you created.

Alternatively, you can write the [custom_url_rewrite_outbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite_outbound/6) and [custom_url_rewrite_inbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6) that allows to rewrite the URLs being shown to the "outside" world, and convert a URL into the one used by Drupal.
The example given in the documentation should make clear how to use this functions.

```
function custom_url_rewrite_inbound(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
  global $user;

  // Change all article/x requests to node/x
  if (preg_match('|^article(/.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
    $result = 'node' . $matches[1];
  }
  // Redirect a path called 'e' to the user's profile edit page.
  if ($path == 'e') {
    $result = 'user/' . $user->uid . '/edit';
  }
}

function custom_url_rewrite_outbound(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  global $user;

  // Change all 'node' to 'article'.
  if (preg_match('|^node(/.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
    $path = 'article' . $matches[1];
  }
  // Create a path called 'e' which lands the user on her profile edit page.
  if ($path == 'user/' . $user->uid . '/edit') {
    $path = 'e';
  }
}
```

In other cases, you can use a module like Pathauto, or [Views Term Path Override](http://drupal.org/project/views_tpo), which allows to override the taxonomy term paths in views.
Other modules that could be of help are [Path redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect), and [Taxonomy Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_redirect); The project page for *Views Term Path Override* suggests [Taxonomy Views Integrator](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) as alternative.

Comment: Views Term Path Override looks promising. Thanks. I'll try that in a bit and see if I have any luck. I'm not sure though if that will live the menu items from Taxonomy Menu intact. Do you know if it would? Or is this for a use-case without Taxonomy Menu?

Comment: It doesn't seem _Views Term Path Override_ is incompatible with _Taxonomy Menu_. You could be interested in what reported in [Using Term Path Override as a menu item](http://drupal.org/node/1026286).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto). I have used it in conjunction with Taxonomy Menu with great results.

Comment: I'm worried about using Pathauto on my site because it's a multilingual site (see: http://drupal.org/node/269877). Is pathauto required for taxonomy menu custom paths?

Comment: Pathauto plays great with multilingual sites

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try http://drupal.org/project/tvi
I'd have success taking over term pages with that. Especially with attachment displays.

This one claims the same thing: http://drupal.org/project/views_tpo