# How to change path of taxonomy facet search

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am using facet search on my site.  The search paths for taxonomy term facets are of the pattern "search/term-name", but I would like them to be of the pattern "search/term-tid".

Is this possible?  How can I change this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taxonomy menu with custom path for taxonomy terms](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/taxonomy-menu-with-custom-path-for-taxonomy-terms)

Comment: hook_term_path($term) this hook only avilable for drupal 6,how to implement in drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

There is a version for Drupal 6 here: [Taxonomy menu with custom path for taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/taxonomy-menu-with-custom-path-for-taxonomy-terms)

However, it uses [`hook_term_path`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_term_path/6), which in Drupal 7 has been replaced by [`hook_entity_info_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7).

Too see note of how to convert this from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7, see guidelines on Drupal.org about  [Converting 6.x modules to 7.x](https://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#hook_url_outbound_alter)